# What topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ generates the Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Given a topological space $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{T})$ where $\mathsf{X}$ is a set and $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on it, one can generate a sigma-algebra using this topology: the Borel sigma algebra
$$
\sigma(\mathcal{T}) = \mathcal{B}(\mathsf{X}).
$$
The classic example is $\mathsf{X} = \mathbb{R}$ in which case we have the Borel sigma-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. However, which topology on $\mathbb{R}$ generates this sigma algebra?

In other words, what is $\mathcal{T}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sigma(\mathcal{T}) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: The usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$. I would write $\mathcal{B}(\textsf{X},\mathcal{T})$ instead of $\mathcal{B}(\textsf{X})$.

Comment: @azif00 Thank you. Is there a proof of this? And thanks for the advice, it makes sense to include the topology in the sigma algebra

Comment: nice question    ... (+1)

Comment: @Physics_Student The proof will exist if you give definition of Borel sets on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Jakobian I am not sure it is that straightforward. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system#Equality_in_distribution) it says that the $\pi$-system $P = \{(-\infty, a]\,:\, a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ generates $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, meaning $\sigma(P) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Yet, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Examples) it says that the topology generated by $P$ is strictly coarser

Comment: It seems there is a lot of confusion in the literature as to which topology on $\mathbb{R}$ would actually generate the usual Borel sigma algebra.

Comment: Do you just want one topology that generates the Borel sigma algebra, or do you want a characterization of all topologies that do this?

Comment: @PhoemueX A characterisation would be nice

Comment: Even though lots of topologies generate $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, the usual definition is always so that this set coincides with the Borel sets of real line with Euclidean topology. This is not something to be confused about. Your example of a topology is a bad one, it has bad separation properties, its not even metrizable. Topology you take is important. This will be more visible when you consider [Radon measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure).

Comment: "I am not sure it is that straightforward." I don't understand what you're referring to. You never defined what $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is so there is no proof to give.

Comment: The reason why we choose $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ to be defined this way is because we want continuous functions $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ to be measurable, and you don't consider them with some arbitrary topology on $\mathbb{R}$, you consider them with respect to the Euclidean topology.

Comment: The reason why you might define $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ in various other ways is a different one. Its about simplicity when verifying that something is Borel. You might choose $P$ as generators, you might choose $\{(-\infty, a) : a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ or all intervals. It doesn't matter. The topology generated by $P$ doesn't matter. What matters is that preimages of those generators need to be measurable. And thats simpler to check if you choose simpler generators

Comment: In some treatments you define $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ to be measurable when sets of the form $\{x : f(x) > a\}$ are measurable. In others its $\{x : f(x) < a\}$. Or $\{x : f(x) \leq a\}$. Again, doesn't matter, all of those are equivalent. And this doesn't even mention sigma-algebras. Think of definition of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ as Borel sigma algebra when $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with Euclidean topology first and foremost, because this is what its supposed to be. All the descriptions of it are supposed to be only helpful. Not canonical in any sense.

Comment: @Physics_Student Maybe this confusion can be resolved by noting that while $\{(-\infty, a): a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ generates the same $\sigma$-algebra as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, it does not generate the same *topology* as the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.